# No audio on concatenating clips in MoviePy

Tags: python-3.x, moviepy

I am trying to concatenate two clips using `MoviePy [ Windows 10 , Python 3.7.4 ]` , but there is no audio in the output video. I can see the temporary audio file while the videos are being concatenated.

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips

clip1 = VideoFileClip("C1.mp4")
clip2 = VideoFileClip("C2.mp4")
final_clip = concatenate_videoclips([clip1,clip2])
final_clip.write_videofile("my_concatenation.mp4")
```

Terminal gives this ouput,

```
Moviepy - Building video my_concatenation.mp4.
MoviePy - Writing audio in %s
MoviePy - Done.
Moviepy - Writing video my_concatenation.mp4

Moviepy - Done !
Moviepy - video ready my_concatenation.mp4
```

I have also tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54722792/output-video-has-no-sound) but it doesn't solve the issue. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Are you on the latest version of MoviePy (v1.0.3)?

Comment: @tburrows13m, I am using version 1.0.0

Comment: Try updating. I think that it was fixed in v1.0.2.

Comment: @tburrows13, this worked : https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/pull/968/files, Should I add this as an answer?

Comment: I've gone ahead and done it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update MoviePy to v1.0.2 or greater, or apply the changes from https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/pull/968 to your installation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by a ffmpeg parameter , just go to moviepy -> video -> io -> ffmpeg_wrtier.py. Then search for ['-i', '-', '-an']. Then change the order into ['-an','-i','-']. Now the audio will work in any player. The first order binds the -an flag to the next stream, which is the audio file (which is subsequently ignored).