# Adding audio to the clip

Tags: python, video, movieclip, moviepy

I have the following code and receiving no sound in the video output. I'm using MoviePy package.

```
from moviepy.editor import *  

picture = VideoFileClip("/Users/name/Desktop/trial.jpg", audio=False).set_duration(50)

txt_clip = TextClip("Hey",fontsize = 150, color='white')
txt_clip = txt_clip.set_pos('center').set_duration(10)

audio = AudioFileClip("/Users/name/Desktop/music.mp3").subclip(0,50)

video_with_new_audio = picture.set_audio(audio)

final_video = CompositeVideoClip([video_with_new_audio,txt_clip])

final_video.write_videofile("trial.mp4")
```

What can be the issue?:c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be a missing MP3 codec, "LAME" etc.? Your code worked on Windows:

```
from moviepy.editor import *  

picture = VideoFileClip("img.jpg", audio=False).set_duration(20)

txt_clip = TextClip("Hey",fontsize = 150, color='white')
txt_clip = txt_clip.set_pos('center').set_duration(10)

audio = AudioFileClip(r"C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\Kalimba.mp3").subclip(0,20)

video_with_new_audio = picture.set_audio(audio)

final_video = CompositeVideoClip([video_with_new_audio,txt_clip])

final_video.write_videofile("trial.mp4")
```

That's the output: [trial.mp4](http://twenkid.com/video/stack/p/trial.mp4)

Can you run `ffprobe trial.mp4` or `ffmpeg -i trial.mp4` and show the output?

That's the output of ffprobe on my video:

```
ffprobe z:\trial.mp4 
(...)
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'z:\trial.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : isom
        minor_version   : 512
        compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
        encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
      Duration: 00:00:20.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 236 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 822x556,
    100 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : VideoHandler
        Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 12
    7 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

That may be related, ffmpeg settings and version of moviepy: [No audio on concatenating clips in MoviePy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62360575/no-audio-on-concatenating-clips-in-moviepy/62374051#62374051)

Answer (score 0):

For many having this issue, I found out, you just have to add the audio codec.

result.write_videofile("output.mp4",  fps=24, audio_codec='aac')