# How to set audio clip on image clip in moviepy?

Tags: python, moviepy

I'm trying to set audio clip on image clip in moviepy. I read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50007811/5132860), then I wrote code like this.

```py
from moviepy.editor import *
clip = ImageClip('img/output_1.png')
audio_clip = AudioFileClip('audio/output_1.mp3')
clip = clip.set_duration(audio_clip.duration)
clip = clip.set_audio(audio_clip)
```

Audio and duration are returns value.

```py
>>> clip.audio
<moviepy.audio.io.AudioFileClip.AudioFileClip object at 0x1241dbd30>
>>> clip.duration
4.18
```

However when I write as file.

```py
clip.write_videofile('mov/sample.mp4',fps=4)
```

I can't hear the sound. Are there any mistake on my code? I don't know how should I change my code... If you have any idea please help me!

My environment is

```
MacOS 11.3.1
python 3.9.5
moviepy 1.0.3
```

I had run same code on google colab, I got same problem. The video has 4.18 seconds, however it's no sound...

I downloaded audio file from [ondoku3](https://ondoku3.com/) and [youtube](https://yt1s.com/en5) as mp3

Comment: do you have this problem when you save only audio? How long is video (duration) when you display in any video player?  maybe it display it with duration 0 (zero) and then it can't play audio.

Comment: When I ran your code, the resulting video wouldn't even play - very strange.

Comment: code works for me on Linux Mint 20, Python 3.8.5, MoviePy 1.0.3. I would check if `mp3` is correct and if video player is not mute

Comment: @knosmos what system, python, moviepy's version did you use? maybe problem is only on some systems? It works for me on Linux.

Comment: Windows 10, Python 3.7.4, moviepy 1.0.3 - I've used moviepy in the past without incident so it probably has something to do with the test files I used

Comment: @furas Hello furas. The video has duration 4 seconds. I got same problem on google colab.

Answer (score 2):

I found QuickTime can't play sound. When I play VLC, I can hear the sound.

And also when I merge audio and video with ffmpeg. I got same problem. So I think this problem from ffmpge convert problem or QuickTime problem.